# Google drive export non-google doc file

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to export several files from Google drive using this code:

```
String str = "application/rft";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, str).executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

and it works properly but, when I try to export an `application/pdf` or `application/png` or `application/jpeg` file I am getting this error:

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Export only supports Google Docs.",
    "reason" : "fileNotExportable"
  } ],
  "message" : "Export only supports Google Docs."
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get this file's content using Java

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Docs can download using [`files.export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export). But when it downloads files (pdf, png and jpeg) except for Google Docs, please use `files().get()`.

You can see the detail information at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file). Also you can see the sample script.

### Edit :

This is a sample script for downloading files except for Google Docs.

```
String fileId = "### file ID ###";
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("### output filename ###");
driveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

Comment: I have tried that but it did not give me the content, just file data such as id, kind, mimeType...

Comment: `out` contains `{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0B2VR-92nUWb9RXJySXhGZUlkckU",
 "name": "10-7-09.pdf",
 "mimeType": "application/pdf"
}` , still not the content. Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: @Aldeguer The script I wrote to my answer works fine in my environment. So can I see your current script?

Comment: It is already working, just forgot "Media" in `executeMediaAndDownload`, thanks a lot dude!!

Comment: @Aldeguer I'm relieved to hear that. Thank you, too.

Comment: it only works for small file size.it did not work for large file size 1 GB the error is OutOfMemoryError Exception