# exportlink for Google drive api v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm switching to the Google drive V3 apis and I'm not able to retrieve the stream to the document.

Goal:  I want to push a google drive document to another location and I need to retrieve the stream of the file in order to use it to push it to the target.

I can't find a way to do it using Google Drive API V3 !

In V2, I used:

```
downloadUrl = file.ExportLinks[(string)ExportTable[file.MimeType]];
```

And then I could use something like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(downloadUrl));
```

I don't find the equivalent in V3.
I tried:

```
 var getfile = _service.Files.Get(file.Id).Execute();
 var request = _service.Files.Export(file.Id, getfile.MimeType);
 System.IO.Stream stream = request.ExecuteAsStream();
```

And the content of the stream is:

```
{
"error": {
 "errors": [
 {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "fileNotExportable",
"message": "Export only supports Google Docs."
}   ],
"code": 403,
"message": "Export only supports Google Docs."
}
}
```

Of course, we don't want to download it to a local file and then generate a new stream from the file cached locally. We want to remain entirely in memory.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Will it work if you use `downloadUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id="+ fileId+"&authuser=0&export=download` ?

Comment: Is this information useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302540/google-drive-export-non-google-doc-file/46310449#46310449

Comment: this is c# not java.  I used .Download 
 instead. It returned a stream but the file has been entirely loaded into memory which is bad. Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.GetRequest getfile = _service.Files.Get(file.Id);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            getfile.Download(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;           
            return stream;

Comment: just resaying what we want: If we move a 2gb file to an alternate location, we want to retrieve a stream to the source file and "stream" the file to the destination. We don't want to eat the memory or the hardrive

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a link yourself if you are logged in as the right user or the file is public with a link:

`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id={{ID}}&exportFormat=pdf`

Comment: Perfect, works ! This link is not widely published

Answer (score 0):

You can see that in the [Migrate to Drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) docs, it says that:

> The exportLinks field has been removed from files. To export Google
>   Documents, use the
>   [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)
>   method instead.

Check that page for other changes in v3 as well.

Comment: files.export does not work. See my initial post, this is what I tried. I want to be able to get a stream to any kind of file.

Comment: Trying to export a native google doc using file.export, I'm systematically getting {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "The requested conversion is not supported.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "convertTo"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The requested conversion is not supported."
 }
}
these new apis are driving me crasy!